# Audio and Video not synced after ffmpeg filter_complex select between

Tags: audio, video, filter, ffmpeg

I am trying to trim a video shoot on an iPhone.

When I execute:

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_8555.MOV \
-filter_complex " \
[0:v] select='between(t,448.856,1279.240)', setpts=N/FR/TB; \
[0:a] aselect='between(t,448.856,1279.240)', asetpts=N/SR/TB \ 
" \ 
output.mov
```

the output audio is out of sync - audio is faster (noticeable towards the end of the output video).

I noticed that the outputs frame rate is 29.97 while the inputs is 29.98.

So I did some experimenting and changed setpts to `setpts=N/29.98/TB;` but still the video is falling behind.
So I changed it even more to `setpts=N/30.00/TB;` - then it feels almost ok.

I tired adding -vsync 1 - no luck

I tried adding -async 1 - no luck

I tried adding -async 7000 - no luck

edit: If i put setpts=N/29.99/TB then it is ideal.

Any ideas how can I make it always synced (no matter what is the input)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 448.86 -to 1279.240 -i IMG_8555.MOV output.mov
```

<addendum>

If you have more cuts, then you can try one of the following 2 approaches:

1. specify them as different inputs then concat

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -to 1 -i IMG_8555.MOV \
       -ss 4 to 5 -i IMG_8555.MOV \
       ...
       -ss 448.86 -to 1279.240 -i IMG_8555.MOV \
       -filter_complex [0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]...[99:v][99:a]concat
       output.mov
```

2. (Unverified but likely work) Use [`concat` demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1). First create a concat file, name it say `IMG_8555_trim.ffconcat` and save it on the same folder as the video file

```
ffconcat version 1.0

file IMG_8555.MOV
inpoint 0 
outpoint 1 

file IMG_8555.MOV
inpoint 4
outpoint 5 

...

file IMG_8555.MOV
inpoint 448.86
outpoint 1279.240
```

then run

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_8555_trim.ffconcat output.mov
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine it multiple times? The example I gave is a minimum example to reproduce the problem, in my project I have like 50+ betweens.

Comment: See the updated post. Yeah, you made it a bit too 'minimal' :-)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I will check it tomorrow! But it looks very promising as this way it doesnt require to use setpts which seems problematic

Comment: It worked! Only I had to add `concat=n=99:v=1:a=1`.

Answer (score 5):

@kesh's method worked for the mentioned problem but it was causing the other overlays (not included in this example) using `enable='between(...)'` to be off sync, so I couldnt go with that solution.

At the end I managed to still use **between** and **setpts** but without using **FRAME_RATE** constant to calculate new **pts** values.

Here is an example of my approach, assuming I want to have 3 cuts like that:

```
[start1, end1]---[start2,end2]---[start3,end3]
```

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov \
[0:v] \
select='between(t,start1,end1)+between(t,start2,end2)+between(t,start3,end3)', \
setpts='PTS-STARTPTS-(gt(T,end1)*(start2-end1) + gt(T,end2)*(start3-end2) )/TB'; \
[0:a] \
aselect='between(t,start1,end1)+between(t,start2,end2)+between(t,start3,end3)', \ 
asetpts='PTS-STARTPTS-(gt(T,end1)*(start2-end1) + gt(T,end2)*(start3-end2) )/TB' \
output.mov
```

Note that `gt(t,100)` returns `1` if it is greather than `100` and `0`  otherwise. I am using it to shift PTS by the gap between previous cuts `(start2-end1)`. If the current `T` is less than `end1` then the value of `gt(T,end1)` will be `0`. So `start2-end1` wont be added (as it is multiplied by zero)

Comment: This solved my problem, but it must be a big T in the gt expression

Comment: same as @Benny , had to use capital T inside the gt expression. e.g. `gt(T,end1)` instead of `gt(t,end1)`